# How to say this sentence right? Will or would? (Indirect speech)

Tags: reported-speech

I would like to know how the following sentence is right.

> Let's help you to decide where you **will/would** put the mirror.

*Would* or *will*, and why?

Comment: My suggestion: *Let's help you decide where you want the mirror*.

Comment: Will sounds more natural to me.

Comment: If you want to sound natural, use @J.R.'s sentence. The format 'help+pronoun' generally does not take any preposition. We put a verb directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's help you to decide where you will put the mirror.

We'll help you find a spot and at some point in the future you will 100% certainly put a mirror there.

> Let's help you to decide where you would put the mirror.

We'll help you find a spot, but you won't put the mirror there unless/until some other condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

will - where the mirror will end up in it's final spot. the final decision

would - more of a hypothetical situation, "Where would you put the mirror if it was smaller?"

"Where will you put the mirror that is the perfect size"